# Images Apparently Automatically Pasting in from one Word doc to another as AutoShapes Causing Issues

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I am trying to copy in an image with overlaid text boxes and arrows from one template to another (these are simple Word docs; not complicated autofill templates). These documents will ultimately be converted into XML, so our rules are that we cannot flatten the image and the arrows/text boxes must remain as editable, separate objects.

In "Image 1" you will see nice, clean easy-to-access grab bars. I can manipulate and move the separate objects easily.

[image: screenshot]

In "Image 2" you see the grey and little tiny autoshape-type grab bars, and to get these on the arrow images is nearly impossible and sometimes IS impossible. And if I can get them to show up, they seem to be entirely useless. Group/Ungroup, etc. are greyed out as well.

[image: screenshot]

Also, this shows up on the page in the background,  {space}SHAPE{space}{space}*MERGEFORMAT with an AutoShape-type frame. And "Automatically Create Drawing Canvas when Inserting AutoShapes" is turned off.

This problem only crops up when I get documents from one of the 3 tech writers on this task.

I have tried so many things, I cannot even recount what I have attempted. I have tried turning off/on a bunch of things in the Advance Options to no avail.

Comment: Any chance the images were "grouped?"

Comment: I have tried both ways, and the problem still crops up. Besides copy/paste, I have also tried to do an "insert" on a flat .jpg and .png. They too insert "incorrectly."

Answer (score 0):

This problem will arise if you're not working with the latest word document format. Usually you will see in the status bar a message `[Compatibility Mode]` next to the filename.

To avoid this,

1. Go to FIle -> INFO -> CONVERT, and your document will be upgraded to the latest version.
2. Either do SAVE or SAVE AS ...
3. Paste your group of objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, saving into the latest version totally screws up the table that is built into the customer-mandated template. I should have guessed that compatibility *might* be part of the problem.